# How do I pass properties to a Backbone view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was developing my app using Backbone v1.0.0 and between beginning work and now there has been an update to v1.1.0. So where I used to be able to do,

```
var myView = new MyView({hash: 'something'});
```

And access `hash` inside the view using,

```
this.options.hash
```

This no longer works. I now get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined

So what's the new way of doing this? I would very much like to be able to pass properties into my view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [1.1.0 ChangeLog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> - Backbone Views no longer automatically attach options passed to the constructor as `this.options`, but you can do it yourself if you prefer.

So the constructor options are still passed to `initialize` but `this.options` is no longer automatically set up. You can do this:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    // Stash `options.hash` in `this` if you want or
    // `this.options = options;` if you want to emulate
    // the old behavior.
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SaJkz/