# Backbone-UI, TableView, rendering columns

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-ui

I'm trying to render a table view with four columns, 'name', 'birthday', 'gender', 'married', but

a) they columns aren't showing up at all
b) I'm not even sure if I am passing them correctly, because when I console.log table.options the columns property is rendered as "empty":

```
Object {columns: Array[0], emptyContent: "no entries", onItemClick: function, sortable: false, onSort: null}
```

I've tried this:

```
var table = new Backbone.UI.TableView({
    model: people,
    columns: [
        { title: "Name", content: 'name' },
        { title: "Gender", content: "gender" } },
        { title: "Birthday", content: "birthday" } },
        { title: "Married", content: "married" }  }
    ]
});
```

And this:

```
var table = new Backbone.UI.TableView({
    model: people,
    options: {
        columns: [
        { title: "Name", content: 'name' },
        { title: "Gender", content: "gender" },
        { title: "Birthday", content: "birthday" },
        { title: "Married", content: "married" }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using the latest Backbone (1.1.0) by chance?

Comment: Yes, Backbone.VERSION = '1.1.0'; Should I dial back a version?

Comment: I think you'll have to drop back a version unless you want to fix the backbone-ui source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19371300/479863 You might want to report a bug to the maintainer as well.

Answer (score 2):

The source code change is adding the options as [mu is too short said](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short). Change the initialize method of the Backbone.UI.TableView object to be the following within the source code:

```
initialize : function(options) { //add parameter
    Backbone.UI.CollectionView.prototype.initialize.call(this, arguments);
    $(this.el).addClass('table_view');
    this._sortState = {reverse : true};
    this.options = _.extend({}, this.options, options); //Add this line
}
```

I'm sure there might be a better place to put this but I'm just going through tutorials to learn some advanced backbone stuff considering the documentation does not match the current version I would shy away from using the library in production as of right now. Hopefully it is fixed in the future.